# Removing Localhost url in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just having a problem trying to properly display an image from an external site but mvc constraints links and automatically adds the localhost: url at the start of everything even with custom routing this cannot be avoided

eg I require: www.google.com/finance/chart?q=NYSE:V&tlf=12

but i am getting: http://localhost:3022/www.google.com/finance/chart?q=NYSE:V&tlf=12

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you just type here some Code how you're getting the URL because it might be a String Concat issue and/or Relative path issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not MVC; it is the formation of your `<a>` tags. You are doing it like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com/finance/chart?q=NYSE:V&tlf=12">blah...</a>
```

You should be doing it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/finance/chart?q=NYSE:V&tlf=12">blah...</a>
```

Without including the protocol at the beginning, the *browser* assumes your link is relative to the current site. It has *nothing whatsoever* to do with MVC.

Comment: This answer applies for both `<a href="">` and `<img src="">`, as well as any other HTML tag attribute which accepts a URI value.

Answer (score 0):

If you require a link on a separate domain, you need to add `http://`

So :

> http://www.google.com/finance/chart?q=NYSE:V&tlf=12

Should work!

Why? Without the `http`, the link is considered relative and the browser uses the relative domain -> `localhost`!