# Why is my external link rendered as internal link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form that let people enter various links on my website like: http, https and ftp. When someone enters "http:stackoverflow.com", "https:stackoverflow.com" and "ftp:stackoverflow.com" and renders these in a view like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var link in Model.Keyword.References)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@link.Link" target="_blank">@link.Link</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I get the following output:

- http:stackoverflow.com
- https:stackoverflow.com
- ftp:stackoverflow.com

This looks fine but when I hover "http:stackoverflow.com" the real link is: "localhost:1973/stackoverflow.com".

When I hover the https and ftp links I get the correct output:

- https://stackoverflow.com
- ftp://stackoverflow.com

I found out that the http links requires two "forward slashes" when I submit them via a form. So instead of "http:" you get "http://". I would like to know why https and ftp links do not need these extra slashes. I would also like to know a good solution for this because I don't think I should force an user to use these extra slashes.

Comment: They actually do need those slashes. They separate the protocol from the URL

Comment: Here is a quick [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756986/removing-localhost-url-in-asp-mvc) that would help. Btw the //: is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slashes in the URL are always required. It could be that your browser does some correction to the invalid url. Try to put https:stackoverflow.com in the addressbar of your browser and it will try to correct it in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As for a good solution, I think you should only accept the domain without http://. You can put some small text underneath the input that shows "Example: 'www.somedomain.com'", so that the user knows the protocol in the front is not needed.

You can then use JQUERY/REGEX to validate and trim off any protocol stuff someone might add mistakingly.